# Insert / update value on mongodb with one comant

Tags: mongodb, nosql, document

In my database, I have a collection with a field called `search`. Now I like to fill this field with the value of other fields.

For example:

Add the value of `title` and `description` to the `search` filed for every document.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you creating this search  field for searching with title and description?

Comment: @Thaks yes, and probably I want to add some other fields as well

Comment: use text indexing for that instead of creating combined fields.Create index in title,description field.Refe: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

Comment: @Thaks the whole application is already built, is there not a way to do it without indexing or in a simpler way?

Comment: Creating index is simple way. Do you have provision to update the query in application?Index creation doesnt affect the application.You can create it in background also.

Comment: @Thaks the application is built that the search is running over one field in the db

Comment: Do you really want to change it into multiple fields?

Comment: dont you have the  provision to change the search query in your application ? or you just want to add more fields into search field and work with the same old query ?

Comment: Yes I need multiple fields

Comment: You need multiple fields without updating your search query right ?

Comment: I recommend you to change the query and use indexing like below.

Answer (score 0):

Create Index for title and description field.

```
 db.myColl.createIndex( { title: 1 ,description:1});
```

Then search simply using below query

```
db.myColl.find({ $text:{$search:"java coffee shop"}})
```